# Github Pages Build Failure with Symlink

Tags: github, github-pages, symlink

I am running into the common *Your site is having problems building: The symbolic link /blue.css targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository.*

I know this is a common issue and have read the [linked documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-symlink-does-not-exist-within-your-site-s-repository/) carefully. The symlink mentioned in the error is in the repo at https://github.com/activescott/blogs.pingpoet.com/blob/master/docs/blue.css and [the linked target](https://github.com/activescott/blogs.pingpoet.com/blob/master/httrack/blogs.pingpoet.com/blue.css) **is in the repository**. In fact, if you hit that link from the GitHub pages published site at http://blogs.pingpoet.com/blue.css, it even works!

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried building and running it locally? https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/ might help troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have a `.nojekyll` file in the docs and root of the repo to turn off jekyll as described at https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/ . So AFAIK running jekyll locally isn't necessary to troubleshoot it is just serving static files.

Comment: i see... btw, not sure why you have one in `docs`, the only one that matters is at the top level.